# Coded, TFS-linked, Automated UI Testing in all browsers

Tags: automation, gui, software-testing

I am looking for a Web UI Testing Tool which:

A. Can test at least IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari;

B. Is not dependent on "recording" and can be purely coded;

C. Can pull data tables from TFS testcases for inputs;

D. Can fail test steps via code (Or has the capability for me to make calls to the TFS API to do so myself)

One problem is that many suites do not work in Safari, and one of our major demographics is a Kiosk'd iPad with Safari.

Other suites are Recorded Actions only, or their "convert to code" I can't figure out how to just skip and do just purely in-code.

I can't find anything that can fail a test step. I may have to code that part myself using the TFS API.

Answer (score 1):

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) is a cross platform, python based, test tool which can use visual recognition of UI elements to decide a) what to click & b) what the results are.  It can generate Pass & Fail results and you can add just about any python code in each test step.

Since it is looking for visual components it should work for just about any browser.

Comment: Awesome suggestion.  But I hate to say that doesn't meet point B.  It's based on screenshots and presentation.  I'm looking for a product that is pure coding, which by proxy means it has to use the DOM.  Though I am somewhat impressed by the utility of Sikuli.

Comment: @Suamere it is based on recognizing screen elements, (not screenshots),  the good news about that approach is that you don't need access to the source, dom or other low level code such as element IDs - if you have access to the button symbols, etc., then you can generate from pure code - you can also generate your tests on one browser and then run them on several others. N.B. I have seen web pages where the buttons had identifiers but were not visible - the DOM approach would not fail them even though they were unusable.